# best way to insert std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, c++03

having:

```
std::map<const std::string,A > cache;
```

how would you insert into this container(duplicate attempt is possible):

```
cache.insert(std::make_pair(id,ps));

cache.insert(std::pair<std::string,A>(id,ps));

if(cache.find(id) == cache.end()){
 cache[id] = ps;
}
```

and why??(in terms of time and memory)

do you have a better solution?

Update:
I am not using C++11

**Update-2:**
OK, so far we realised that:

`make_pair` and `pair<>` are analogous.

`insert` and `[ ]`(with or without `if`checking) will both invoke `copy`. So.. Is the competition  between :

1. `insert`
2. `[ ]`(with`if`checking)
3. `[ ]`(with`if`checking and [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25401075/805896))

which one would you prefer?

thanks again

Comment: `cache[id] = ps;` without check

Comment: AFAIK `std::make_pair` is just a shorthand function for `std::pair<a,b>` as you do not need to define the types (they are automatically deduced).

Comment: `cache.insert(std::pair<std::string const&, A const&>(id,ps));`

Comment: @BryanChen But that changes the semantics

Comment: `cache.emplace(id, ps)` if you have C++11. Clearly not the last one as that searches the map two times. And surely not the 2nd one either since the 1st one is a cleaner and more streamlined way to write that anyway. Hmm, maybe I should just have written an answer.

Comment: @Angew what's the difference?

Comment: @BryanChen `insert()` doesn't change the element if it's already present.

Comment: cache.insert(std::pair<std::string,A>(id,ps)) will not forward the value, it will copy it, because the value_type for map is std::pair<const std::string...>. Note the const.

Comment: @BryanChen cache[id] = ps; without check is not what I want. It changes the semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cache.insert(std::make_pair(id,ps));
```

This will copy `id` and `ps`. If they have "heavy" copy constructors this will waste some time and memory.

```
cache.insert(std::pair<std::string,A>(id,ps));
```

Its indeed analog for `make_pair`

```
if(cache.find(id) == cache.end()){
 cache[id] = ps;
}
```

Its better to use without check: `cache[id] = ps;`. But, at first element insertion the "default" object of type `decltype(ps)` will be constructed. Then, its assigned (using `operator=`) to `ps`. If its heavy, this can be problem too. But, i think its preferred way if **swap** method is not available.

```
cache.emplace(id, ps);
```

This can look like zero-copy emplace, but its not. `emplace` receives **constructor parameters**, so default copy constructor will be called. Also its C++11.

I think most efficient way is

```
cache[id].swap(ps);
```

This should make minimum amount of copies, but drawback is your `ps` will be reset (or contain old value).

Comment: Actually I was looking for such an answer-comparing the copy operations between `insert` and `[ ]`. Does this mean, both `insert` and `[ ]` will do a copy anyway? does it mean they dont differ much?

Comment: @rahman this can depend on implementation. With `insert` it can be a copy constructor + assign operation. In case `[]` you know it will be only create empty+assign operation, which should be faster anyway. `swap` will just swap object guts and should have constant time.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );

// usage:
cache.emplace(id, ps);
```

But, it depends a bit on whether you want a second insertion to

- fail (as the above would, returning a `std::pair<iterator,bool>` in which `.second` indicates successful insertion or failure - you can ignore that if you don't care, as the only reason for failure is an existing key) or
- overwrite the existing value (for which it's easiest and usually perfectly adequate to write `cache[id] = ps;`, but if you want to avoid default construction of an element pair then you can use `find` and then overwrite an existing or `emplace` a new element as necessary).

Occasionally you might want to consider marking one or both of the parameters as movable-from (i.e. you don't care what (valid) state the local variable is left in after the `emplace` returns, which may allow extra optimisations).  You can see from the prototype above that the arguments are accepted using `&&` which hints at capability to perform such optimnisations.

```
cache.emplace(std::move(id), std::move(ps));
```

Comment: In this case emplace will not do what it designed for.

Comment: @PSIAlt that's not true (given my understanding of what it's designed for, which is probably less than some people might hope for) but it's also vague enough that I've nothing meaningful to dispute... care to elaborate?

Comment: emplace receives argument list, which will be forwared to constructor for new objects. Because you give a `std::string` as a initializer list - objects will be created using default copy constructor, which is not most efficient in terms of cpu-memory.

Comment: @PSIAlt I thought you might mean that... the question doesn't say what the type of `id` is - it could be e.g. a `const char*` to a string literal in which case the `std::string` will be constructed once where needed - nor anything about the types of `A` and `ps`, but I agree it could be a consideration for some types, if there's any actual reason to construct complex variables before the `emplace` line itself.  `std::move()` on the `emplace` parameters is a natural solution where a local copy needn't be retained.

Comment: Nice discussion, but... I didn't mean C++11 (updated the question accordingly)

Answer (score 5):

The third one is clearly inferior in terms of time, since it requiers two lookups in the map when actually doing the insertion (one for `find()` and one for `[]`). So stick to the `insert()` function.

Now the question is: `std::make_pair()` or `std::pair<A, B>()`? It's generally a good idea to follow the principle of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), which means you shouldn't repeat the types, so use `std::make_pair()`.

If you have C++11, the best option is to use `emplace()`:

```
cache.emplace(id, ps);
```

---

As a side note, it's pointless to type the map as `std::map<const std::string, A>`. Keys in a map are already immutable; it's more concise (and doesn't produce a WTF moment) to just use `std::map<std::string, A>`, and you'll be really hard pressed to find a case where those two differ.

Comment: Depending on required behavior on duplicate keys, `[]` can be strictly better. Although given the `if` guard in question, this is probably moot.

Comment: @Xarn `std::map` does not allow duplicate keys. And all 3 of the OP's examples leave the value untouched when the key is already present, so I assume that's the intended behaviour. Can `[]` be better in this situation?

Comment: `std::map<...>::value_type(id,ps)` is much better than the `pair` and `make_pair` solutions.